# Efficient way for manipulating binary data

Tags: php, binary-data

I have a string containing bitmap data. Basically, it holds cycles of 1 byte of red, green, blue for each pixel in an image.

I want to manipulate the 8-bit integer value of each color channel in the bitmap. Currently I do this using `unpack('C'.strlen($string))` which gives me an array of integers. This is very slow as it converts a lot of data.

**Is there a more efficient way to access and modify data from a string as integers?**

By more efficient, I mean more efficient than this:

```
for($i = 0, $l = strlen($string); $i < $l; $i++)
    $string[$i] = chr(floor(ord($string[$i]) / 2));
```

The manipulation where I divide by 2 is simply an example. The manipulations would be more advanced in a real example.

The problem with the above example is that for say 1 million pixels, you get 3 million function calls initialized from PHP (`chr`, `floor`, `ord`). On my server, this amounts to about 1.4 seconds for an example picture.

Comment: When someone is asking about more efficient ways to do something, it is absurd to say that it is an opinion based question. Efficiency is easily measurable in terms of raw time measurements.

Answer (score 1):

PHP strings essentially are byte arrays. The fastest way would simply be:

```
for ($i = 0, $length = strlen($data); $i < $length; $i++) {
    $byte = $data[$i];

    ...
}
```

If you manipulate the byte with bitwise operators, you'll hardly get more efficient than that. You can write the byte back into the string with `$data[$i] = $newValue`. If you need to turn a single byte into an int, use `ord()`, the other way around use `chr()`.

Comment: This does not work: $byte = $data[$i] * 0.5 and I'll make a test to see if millions of calls to ord() is faster than unpack('C'.strlen($data), $data)

Comment: As I said, `$byte` is a raw byte. Use bitwise operators to work on it. If you want to use integer arithmetic instead, turn it into an integer with `ord`.

Comment: So I should try $data[$i] >> 1 instead? Do you know of sources for doing more fine grained bitwise operations? Like how to multiply by 0.9 using bitwise operations.

Comment: Doing any math other than by powers of 2 is going to be tricky using bitwise operators. Again: `chr(ord($byte) * 0.5)`, for example.

Comment: chr(ord($byte) >> 1) is slower than going the unpack()-route. Casting does not work either; $c = (int) " "; // 0, should be 32

Comment: `ord($byte) >> 1` makes little sense and `(int)" "` should certainly not be 32 by PHP's casting rules. What exactly *are* you trying to do? You say you could do it in C, so I'd have assumed you knew the binary operation you're trying to do.

Comment: In C you can manipulate each byte of a string as any other uint8. In PHP you can't. So in C it makes sense to do something like data[2] >> 1. In PHP $data[2] >> 1 yields 0, so I have to do ord($data[2]) >> 1. PHP is not casting, it seem to be converting - using casting syntax.